# Android ImageButton and Spinner not working

Tags: android

When user clicks on icon adjacent to the item in spinner, some action has to be performed. i have not added functionality for button click handler. Before that i am facing below issue. For button with icon, i have used ImageButton in Spinner.

But when item in spinner is selected, all the items are shown and list down is not closing.

I am using Android api 28 to test.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ravispinner;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<FileItem> mList;
    private FileAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initList();

        Spinner spinnerCountries = findViewById(R.id.spinner_countries);

        mAdapter = new FileAdapter(this, mList);
        spinnerCountries.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        spinnerCountries.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                FileItem clickedItem = (FileItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getName();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clickedCountryName + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void initList() {
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mList.add(new FileItem("Edit", R.drawable.ic_action_edit));
        mList.add(new FileItem("New", R.drawable.ic_action_new));
        mList.add(new FileItem("Remove", R.drawable.ic_action_remove));

    }
}
```

FileAdapter

```
package com.example.ravispinner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FileItem> {

    public FileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FileItem> countryList) {
        super(context, 0, countryList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.file_spinner_row, parent, false
            );
        }

        ImageButton imageViewFlag = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_flag);
        TextView textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);

        FileItem currentItem = getItem(position);

        if (currentItem != null) {

            //imageViewFlag.setImageResource(currentItem.getFlagImage());
            textViewName.setText(currentItem.getName());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

FileItem

```
package com.example.ravispinner;

public class FileItem {
    private String mName;
    private int mFlagImage;

    public FileItem(String name, int flagImage) {
        mName = name;
        mFlagImage = flagImage;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public int getFlagImage() {
        return mFlagImage;
    }
}
```

file_spinner_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_view_flag"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_view_flag"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="India"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ravispinner.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TableRow android:layout_margin="2dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Test Scenario\t: "
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />
    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one more solution to achieve UI try once may it helps you.
change your file_spinner_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:text="India"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_remove_circle_24" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Test Scenario:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow i am seeing build error when using above code. If possible, can you please make changes in my code files which i shared, so i can use them to build and test.

Comment: @vrreddy1234 Check once I have updated XML file and tested from my end.please check from your end.